# variable-variables in PHP

Tags: php, variable-variables

I know you can do: `$hash('foo')` and `$$foo` and also `$bar[$foo]`, what are each of these things called?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- **`$hash('foo')` is a variable function.**
  `$hash` may contain a string with the function name, or an anonymous function.

  ```
  $hash = 'md5';

  // This means echo md5('foo');
  // Output: acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8
  echo $hash('foo');
  ```
- **`$$foo` is a variable variable.**
  `$foo` may contain a string with the variable name.

  ```
  $foo = 'bar';
  $bar = 'baz';

  // This means echo $bar;
  // Output: baz
  echo $$foo;
  ```
- **`$bar[$foo]` is a variable array key.**
  `$foo` may contain anything that can be used as an array key, like a numeric index or an associative name.

  ```
  $bar = array('first' => 'A', 'second' => 'B', 'third' => 'C');
  $foo = 'first';

  // This tells PHP to look for the value of key 'first'
  // Output: A
  echo $bar[$foo];
  ```

The PHP manual has an article on [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), and an article on [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (but I didn't show an example above for the latter).

Comment: Variable array keys are pretty staple. I've included the PHP manual links for variable variables and variable functions.

Comment: Things get really funny if you use the extended variable syntax. This allows stuff like `${'prefix_' . $name}` or even funnier things like `${$var = 'var'}` (this is `'var'`).

Comment: +1: "Variable function" calls can also be used on objects that declare an `__invoke` magic method (Since PHP 5.3).  So it can handle string function names, the return from `create_function()`, a `Closure` object (which is created when you use anonymous functions since 5.3) or a generic object which declares a `__invoke` method.  It's too bad you can't use it on other callback types (`array('classname', 'methodname')`)...